# Shouldn't the questions and accepted answers parallel each other in votes?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, accepted-answer

I have seen many questions in which the question and the accepted answer will have different amount of votes. For instance, the question will have 8 votes, whereas the accepted answer will have 15. However, shouldn't they really be identical? After all, an answer is only as good as the question it's answering...

What do you guys think?

Comment: No, they shouldn't. We can have a excellent answer in a normal question and vice versa. The accepted answer may not be the best answer.

Comment: @JorgeB. in my opinion that's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @ANeves I have to improve my answer.

Answer (score 6):

No, they shouldn't. We can have a excellent answer in an ordinary question and vice versa. The accepted answer may not be the best answer. The accepted answer is the answer that helps the OP to clarify his doubt.